# Uncaught TypeError: Object function(a,b) has no method 'fancybox'

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox-2

The project is using fancyBox v2.0.5 with jQuery v1.7.2, and my javascript code is:

```
function getWeather() {
    $("body").css("cursor", "progress");
    console.log("click");

    url = 'index.php?model=weather_page';
    $.ajax({
        async: false,
        type: 'GET',
        url: url
    }).done(function(data) {
            $.fancybox({
                'width'             : 850,
                'height'            : 850,
                'speedIn'           : 800,
                'autoScale'         : true,
                'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
                'easingIn'          : 'easeOutBack',
                'easingOut'         : 'easeInBack',
                'type'              : 'inline',
                'scrolling'         : 'auto',
                'closeBtn'          : true,
                'closeClick'        : true,
                'content'           : data,
                'onComplete' : function(){
                    $.fancybox.resize();
                },
            });
            $("body").css("cursor", "auto");
        });
}
```

Which is run at the onclick event:

```
<div id="miniWeatherBlock" onclick="getWeather()">
    // data for mini-weather block
</div>
```

The event runs fine when I first click it, it loads the data returned from the AJAX in a fancybox pop-up. However after I close this then click on the same miniWeatherBlock again, it doesn't load a pop-up and in the console I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}
>   has no method 'fancybox'

At line where I use `$.fancybox({`

Any ideas what's wrong?

**EDIT:**
    
        // snippet of head

```
<script src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>

<script src="js/functions.js"></script>
</head>
```

Inside `js/functions.js` - I have the getWeather() function.

Other instances of fancybox work perfectly fine, for example, this is also inside the `js/functions.js` file:

```
$(".fancybox-information").fancybox({
    'width'             : 720,
    'height'            : 1300,
    'speedIn'           : 800,
    'autoScale'         : true,
    'transitionIn'      : 'elastic',
    'transitionOut'     : 'elastic',
    'easingIn'          : 'easeOutBack',
    'easingOut'         : 'easeInBack',
    'type'              : 'iframe',
    'scrolling'         : 'no',
    'closeBtn'          : true,
    'closeClick'        : true
});
```

Which works fine when the page has elements with the class `fancybox-information`

Comment: the plugin is not included properly..

Comment: @zzlalani I include jQuery before fancybox in my head of the page and it works fine for all other instances, it's just this getWeather() function that isn't working right. It works fine the first time you click it to open it, but not the second time...

Comment: Are you inclunding jQuery again somewhere in your code?

Comment: @IrvinDomininakaEdward hmm seems the weather page that gets returned was including jQuery again and I have no idea why... removed it and it works fine now, Many thanks! So including jQuery 'again' causes problems with 'jQuery plugins' that were already loaded with a previous 'jQuery' version? Could you write your comment as an answer so I can mark it done :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you are inclunding jQuery core library again somewhere in your code.

This cause that jQuery (and its alias $) will be reseted and any plugin attached to it removed.